# telegram python telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

необходимо пройтись по каналам группам чатам в telegram и собрать информацию о них и получить сообщения.

Проблема в том что при получении канала/группы/чата `entity = client.get_entity(canal)` через какое-то количество запросов кидает задержку на 4 минуты, потом продолжается, а потом кидает задержку на 24 часа.

А сообщени я все так же могу получать, но именно параметры группы/канала/чата не могу посмотреть.
Как можно обойти данную проблему?

Comment: удалось решить проблему?

Comment: @garrythehotdog нет, это ограничение от telegram, на один аккаунт до 200 в день

Comment: т.е. один бот может получить entity о 200 группах в сутки? я правильно понял?

Comment: @garrythehotdog возможно даже меньше, на сообщения это вроде не распространяется